# Spider a website following a pattern

Tags: windows, web-crawler, wget

I'm trying to save into a text document only the urls of a website which begin by "website.com/A" (using Wget for windows from the command prompt, so unix commands can't be used in my case).

If I want to save all the urls of "somewebsite.com", the following command works:

```
wget --spider --recursive --no-verbose --output-file=wgetlog.txt http://somewebsite.com
sed -n "s@.\+ URL:\([^ ]\+\) .\+@\1@p" wgetlog.txt | sed "s@&@\&amp;@" > sedlog.txt
```

But now, if I only want to save the urls of "somewebsite.com" which begin by "somewebsite.com/A", what parameters should I add to the command above ? I tried I or A paramaters but it didn't work.

Comment: why not use a programming language with a module to help do this for you? you don't need to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: I precisely use Wget because it has been developed for my need, like httrack. Using these tools is not reinventing the wheel, I don't get you ;p

Comment: I just mean you could use something like WWW::Mechanize in perl to get links

Comment: I don't have sufficient knowledge in perl to do that. By the way Wget is a light and powerful stuff, I'm just blocked because of a parameter I don't know how to use.

Comment: _"unix commands can't be used in my case"_ - well, `sed` **is** a unix command. Do you have a set of unix tools for Windows, including `grep`?

Comment: All solutions I tried using 'grep' returned me an error inside the Windows command prompt. Now you come to mention it, it's very strange the command works with 'sed'.